# Create a cumulative variable for duration sum only if gaps between duration is one day

Tags: arrays, loops, sas, duration, accumulate

I am trying to calculate duration of how long a patient received an antimicrobial. Every patient has multiple intervals. For example, a patient started receiving drug from day 1 to day 4, then continued receiving it from day 6 to day 9. For this subject, I will ignore day 5 and total duration is 8. On the other hand, another subject received drug from day 1 to day 3, and then received it from day 8 to day 12. For this subject, duration is only 3 days because the gap was significant (i.e. greater than 1 day). I tried to use array and do loop to calculate total duration. Maximum number of intervals are 20 so my arrays are that long. I tried to run through each interval and see if gap between each interval is acceptable or not. I think my conditions are pretty clearly laid out.
Conditions are: (FYI, gap is difference between new start of an interval and old stop of an interval)

if gap is lt 0, check stop date of interval. If stop date is less than or equal to old stop date, don't change total duration. If stop date is greater than old stop date, add difference of new and old stop dates to total duration.

if gap is 0 or 1, then calculate duration as new stop-old start+1.

if gap is 2, then calculate duration as new stop-old start.

if gap is 3, then I want it to stop accumulating duration completely.

I am having issue with trying to stop the loop whenever the first gap is bigger than acceptable (i.e. greater than 1 day). for some reason, my code keeps running if it finds a later gap that is acceptable when it should stop running because previous gap was not acceptable. hope the question is clear. thank you!

this is the population

| Subject | Start1 | Stop1 | Start2 | Stop2 | Start3 | Stop3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ONE | 1MAY11 | 3MAY11 | 5MAY11 | 20MAY11 | 23MAY11 | 25MAY11 |
| TWO | 1MAY11 | 3MAY11 | 10MAY11 | 20MAY11 | 20MAY11 | 25MAY11 |
| THREE | 1MAY11 | 7MAY11 |  |  |  |  |
| FOUR | 1MAY11 | 3MAY11 | 2MAY11 | 12MAY11 | 8MAY11 | 10MAY11 |

the resulting variable will be added at the end as total duration

| Subject | Start1 | Stop1 | Start2 | Stop2 | Start3 | Stop3 | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ONE | 1MAY11 | 3MAY11 | 5MAY11 | 20MAY11 | 23MAY11 | 25MAY11 | 19 |
| TWO | 1MAY11 | 3MAY11 | 10MAY11 | 20MAY11 | 20MAY11 | 25MAY11 | 3 |
| THREE | 1MAY11 | 7MAY11 |  |  |  |  | 7 |
| FOUR | 1MAY11 | 3MAY11 | 2MAY11 | 12MAY11 | 8MAY11 | 10MAY11 | 12 |

I think I just need to update start and stop date every time I am trying to compare it to next interval. I cannot share my code right now since it is a bit messy. I will try to post it later.

Comment: Please post sample data in `datalines` format and your expected output from your examples.

Comment: just added the tables and different scenarios and what resulting values should be.

Comment: Can you post your code as well?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you need the program to stop counting days as soon at it reaches a gap of longer than 1 day.

The code to do this is:

```
data have;
    input Subject $ Start1  Stop1   Start2  Stop2   Start3  Stop3 ;
    informat start1-start3 stop1-stop3 date7.;
    format start: stop: date7.;
    datalines;
ONE 01MAY11 03MAY11 05MAY11 20MAY11 23MAY11 25MAY11
TWO 01MAY11 03MAY11 10MAY11 20MAY11 20MAY11 25MAY11
THREE 01MAY11 07MAY11 . . . .
FOUR 01MAY11 03MAY11 02MAY11 12MAY11 08MAY11 10MAY11
;
run;


data want;
    set have;
    max_intervals=3;
    retain duration;
    array starts {*} start:;
    array stops {*} stop:;
    duration=stop1 - start1 + 1; * start with the duration equal to the length of the first interval;
    do i = 2 to max_intervals;
        if starts(i) > stops(i-1)+2 then leave; * large gap found - exit DO loop and output duration result for this row ;
        if stops(i) <= stops(i-1) then continue; * skip this interval if it ended before the end of the previous interval;
        if starts(i) <= stops(i-1) then duration + stops(i) - stops(i-1); * dont double-count days if there is an overlap;
        else duration + stops(i) - starts(i) + 1; * otherwise add the length of the current interval to the total duration;
    end;
    drop max_intervals i;
run;
```

Comment: I think this should work. I ended up running the do loop. I just said that if starts(i) > stops(i-1)+2 then all next gaps become that. if gaps are acceptable, it calculates duration as you have laid out. thank you for this!